# python pip migrating libraries from ~/.local to /usr/local/lib

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I'm looking for a way on Ubuntu to quickly move all libraries installed to ~./local by pip install xxx --user, to /usr/local which is my global python library location.

Comment: `pip freeze > requirements.txt && pip install -r requirements.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create and use a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/). It is recommended to manage python packages and versions.

If you want to move / reinstall all your packages, pip can generate a list of installed packages with [pip freeze](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/), in a requirement.txt format. So you can reinstall everything anywhere you want using.

`pip install -r requirements.txt --target=/path/`

You could also directly copy site-packages folders, but I would not recommend it.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I was looking for!